# Why does an applescript not detect success after creating via dragging from a "watch me do" recording?

Tags: applescript, automator

Background: My goal here is to gather connection speed data that my ISP will accept so I can demonstrate dramatic drops in connection speed lasting 1-5 minutes that I've been experiencing immediately after switching to this new ISP (same equipment - with no prior such speed inconsistencies).  They only accept (and can access) connection speed test results by using their speed test website when run from a wired computer (i.e. not one connected via Wifi).

So I created a quick little automator workflow that generally works... unless the connection speed drops out and the website doesn't respond - which thwarts my entire goal!

I had initially recorded the following initial actions in a watch-me-do:

1. Click Safari in the dock
2. Click a bookmarks folder
3. Click the bookmark for the speed test website
4. Click the speed test start button

which is followed by processing of the results that generally works and is fault tolerant.  However, there are 2 things that can happen which lead to a fatal error in the workflow:

1. The web page doesn't load
2. The web page loads but the speed test start button doesn't load (the page initially shows a loading graphic where the button will appear)

I am fine with the occasional test failing.  I have code that parses the text on the page and such results show up in the log as a test failure with a timestamp.

However, the script issues an error when it can't click the button and all further testing stops, so I tried dragging the button-click action from the watch-me-do into the workflow, which becomes an editable applescript.  I figured I could edit the script to change the error call inside the `on error` block.  The resulting workaround sort of works, but now it appears that it NEVER thinks the button is getting successfully clicked and eventually hits the time-out, goes into `on error`, and runs the line I added: `exit repeat`.

So what is going on here?  Why does the script appear to not detect that the click action was performed successfully?

Here's the code from the button click action dragged from the watch-me-do:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- Click the “Start” button.
    tell application "Safari" to activate  --I added this line
    delay 6.095782
    set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
    set uiScript to "click UI Element \"Start\" of group 1 of group 2 of UI Element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"Speed Test\" of application process \"Safari\""
    my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    return input
end run

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                exit repeat  --I replaced an error call here
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

- I redacted ISP particulars (see comments below).

Comment: TLDR.  What's the website URL for the speed test ?

Comment: Well, I didn't want to reveal the ISP for 2 reasons. 1. They appear to have gone to come effort to prevent scripting of their webpage, so I didn't want them to find this post and try to thwart my script. 2. I didn't want to publicly malign this ISP for poor consistency before I was able to show it with my test results. I'm not using one of their supported routers, so it's possible the issue is due to an incompatibility. That's why my question is about clicking a bookmark instead of clicking their start test button.

Comment: And sorry about the question length. Succinctness is not one of my strong suits.

Comment: You just want to click the bookmark in _Safari_ ?

Comment: I want to click it in Safari, yes, but more specifically, I want to do it via an applescript action so that I can do something other than throw an error if the click fails.

Comment: I get similar behavior from the following action about clicking the button on the page.  That action is more likely to fail and is really what this question is about, but I thought that making this question about the bookmark click further isolates the problem to something going on with the applescript, and removes the web page from the equation. It's the same erroneous behavior.

Comment: Perhaps the behaviour seems similar, but the solutions are different.  For one, you don't need to click on the _Safari_ bookmark to take you to the webpage.  AppleScript can take you there by itself, by controlling _Safari_ directly.  Would that be useful if I showed you how to do that ?

Comment: You know, I had the same thought just before you responded. I could just open a URL via a shell script or applescript call.  Sheesh.  Such a simple work-around.  I was too focussed on the reason why what I was trying wouldn't work.  But you're right, I should try to solve the issue with the button specifically.

Comment: JavaScript is your friend.

Comment: OK, I just tried out using an open call with the URL and that works great. I can still see however that the code to click the button is clicking it and then timing out. I have the workaround to not issue an error, so the overall result is OK, but I'd still like to figure out why the applescript doesn't know the click succeeded. I'll update my question.

Comment: Incidentally, before I used the shell script call, I'd tried using a couple Safari actions from the library in automator, but they fail due to a security error that I can't seem to alleviate. The shell script action works fine though.

Comment: Does this have to be done in  AppleScript?  Why can't this be done using `curl`?

Comment: Well, I’m not sure how to wait for the button to appear on the page or wait for the test to complete if I were to use curl. I don’t think the button is a form button ora link. I think it may be flash or something. I’m not sure.

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid, but maybe you could save the page offline and the button will always load? Than you click and go online? Also how many tests do you need to prove your point? Does it worth creating a workflow instead of doing it manually, say, 10 times?

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a plot of average dl speed throughout the day from my ISP. I'm supposed to get 100 down, 100 up. The data was collected over the course of 9 days, running a test roughly every 4.5 minutes. I binned the data in 4 minute bins. Lines show average & minimum speeds, plus number of measurements. Dots show number of (ISP's) speed test errors and (my) script failures. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wf6gv8hbmjavdc/speed_consistency_plot_refined.png?dl=0